# Motherboard too hot?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, gpu

On a new PC I just bought, Speccy reports that the motherboard is too hot:

[image]

Since the CPUs and GPU are only at 30C, and 110C is really very hot, I suspect that the reported Motherboard temperature is wrong.

Still, I'd like to know how I can find out, and what to do about it.

The PC was configured by a professional Gaming PC shop. It has a GTX 780 graphics card, a Intel i7 4770 CPU, and water-cooling.

Comment: Considering the shop configured it for you, you could ask them?

Comment: Yep I will. I was just hoping for an answer like `Speccy's Motherboard temperature measuring is buggy` :)

Comment: You could always get a thermometer and measure.  Small digital cooking thermometers are available for about $10 in the kitchen areas of department stores.  The trick is to achieve good contact with the surface you want to measure.

Comment: Not all temperature sensors on motherboards work the same and the manufacturers do not always release how they work. As a result a lot of programs take educated guesses and then present the numbers. Sometimes this works. Sometimes it does not. To be sure only use the monitoring programs which you got when you bought the motherboard. Those have been tested for your MB by the manufacturers. Anything else is guesswork at best, and can crash the whole PC in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Try with couple other temperature monitoring programs. I had similar situation with my old PC where [SpeedFan](http://download.cnet.com/SpeedFan/3000-2094_4-10067444.html), [CoreTemp](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Windows-Widgets/Widget-Miscellaneous/Core-Temp.shtml) and [SIW](http://download.cnet.com/SIW-Portable/3000-2094_4-75449686.html) were reporting `CPU` temperatures ~120C degrees. But in the `BIOS`, I could see `CPU` temperature is ~60C, and there was enabled setting in `BIOS` to turn PC off when `CPU` temp comes up to 90C. So, most probably - bad sensor readings. One more temperature monitoring app [HWMonitor](http://download.cnet.com/HWMonitor/3000-2094_4-10793486.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, those other tools show just the CPU temperature, and not that of the motherboard.

Comment: @cheeesus I think they do read temperatures from sensors on the motherboard. Maybe not all of them, and maybe showing results like _system temp_ or something similar. Try with these: [link](http://www.hmonitor.com/), [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tempmonitor/) or [link](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Motherboard-Monitor.shtml)